# Understanding the Python requests module

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, python-requests

So I'm currently learning the python requests module but I'm a bit confused and was wondering if someone could steer me in the right direction. I've seen some people post headers when they want to log into the website, but where do they get these headers from and when do you need them? I've also seen some people say you need an authentication token, but I've seen some other solutions not even use headers or an authentication token at all. This is supposedly the authentication token but I'm not sure where to go from here after I post my username and password.

```
<input type="hidden" name="lt" value="LT-970332-9KawhPFuLomjRV3UQOBWs7NMUQAQX7" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Although your question is a bit vague, I'll try to help you.

#### Authentication

A web browser (client) can authenticate on the target server by providing  data, usually the pair login/password, which is usually encoded for security reasons.

This data can be passed from client to server using the following parts of HTTP request:

1. URL parameters (http://httpbin.org/get?foo=bar)
2. headers
3. body (this is where `POST` parameters from `HTML` forms usually go)

#### Tokens

After successful authentication server generates a unique token and sends it to client. If server wants client to store token as a cookie, it includes `Set-Cookie` header in its response.

A token usually represents a unique identifier of a user session. In most cases token has an expiration date for security reasons.

Web browsers usually store token as a cookie in internal cookie storage and use them in all subsequent requests to corresponding website. A single website can use multiple tokens and other cookies for a single user.

#### Research

Every web site has its own authentication format, rules and restrictions, so first thing you need to do is a little research on target website. You need to get information about the client sends auth information to server, what server replies and where session data is being stored (usually you can find it in client request headers).

In order to do that, you may use a proxy ([Burp](https://portswigger.net/burp) for example) to intercept browser traffic. It can help you to get the data passed from client to server and back.

Try to authenticate and then browse some pages on target site using your web browser with a proxy. After that, using your proxy, examine what parts of HTTP request/response do client and browser use to store information about sessions and authentication.

After that you can finally use python and `requests` to do what you want.